# Django Models not showing in template

Tags: django, django-models

I am finding it quite difficult to display django models in template. The Model does not show at all in the template. Any help will indeed be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime


class Blog(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    company= models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    post = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author= models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    mantra= models.CharField(max_length = 200, help_text='make it short and precise')
    photo= models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/jobs/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=False, null=False)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default =True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self): 
   return reverse('index')
```

### **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Blog

class Home(ListView):
  model = Blog
  context_object_name = 'test'
  template_name='test.html'
  fields = ['name', 'company', 'post', 'author', 'mantra', 'continent', 'photo']
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import Home

urlpatterns=[
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

### Template

```
<p>{{test.name}}</p>
<p>{{test.author}}</p>
<p>{{test.post}}</p>
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)? There is a very simple template example there.

Comment: Did you loop on them ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop on the queryset:

```
{% for object in test %}
      <p>{{object.name}}</p>
      <p>{{object.author}}</p>
      <p>{{object.post}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```